# Word for giant outdoor posters on buildings

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the giant, larger-than-life outdoor ads/posters hung on the walls of buildings (often tens of floors high), e.g Godzilla, Jurassic Park, Stalin... (something similar to a [billboard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/billboard)?)

EDIT: Five stackexchange puritans put the question on hold, but I think wallscapes, supergraphics and billboards are good answers. I think this post will be useful for other users with a similar question. Thank you! In response to, Ibf, Chappo, JJJ, marcellothearcane, David M, and the rest of of your ilk with too much time in their hands: I will be using this knowledge in my **everyday speak** and I did suggest the term "billboard," which should demonstrate my "research" on the topic. Some people...

Comment: They are considered *billboards*. I don't think a printed poster would actually be able to survive the elements for very long.

Answer (score 3):

[Wallscape](https://www.imagemediaoutdoor.com/wallscapes/):

> Often found in major metropolitan areas, a wallscape is a large mural that is either painted, plastered or attached to the exterior of a building. These forms of outdoor advertisements are primarily used to give a company a dominating presence.

(imagemediaoutdoor.com)

[image]

(Clearchaneloutdoor.com)

Answer (score 2):

Very large banners and posters are sometimes referred to as ***[supergraphics](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/supergraphics)*** (M/W). The term, in camel case, is also a mark for a large format printing [company](https://supergraphics.com/).